# Excluding a file while copying

Tags: c#, copy

I want to copy all files from the current folder to another folder inside that.
but excluding few files which is a .exe file and a .dll file.

this is the code i have right now, this copies every file from current to the other folder. i have searched and got few answers to exclude based on the extensions but that isnt what i was looking for. i want to exclude based on their name so that i can exclude more files later on.

```
string TargetDirectory = @"Copied";
if (Directory.Exists(TargetDirectory))
{
    Directory.Delete(TargetDirectory, true);
}

Directory.CreateDirectory(TargetDirectory);
await Task.Delay(1000);

string SourceDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Logger.LogInfo("Creating Backup of the Source Directory...");            
if (Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory).Length == 0)
{
     Logger.LogError("No Files found in this directory. " + SourceDirectory);
     return;
}
else
{   
    //Now Create all of the directories         
    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourceDirectory, TargetDirectory));

    //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourceDirectory, TargetDirectory), true);
}
```

Comment: Instead of excluding why don't you copy only what you need?

Comment: the folder contains 300+ files with different extensions and different names. including many sub folders as well. i dont think copying only what i need is a good way to be honest. 
the files i need to exclude are very less, like just 3 or 4.

Comment: Just put the files you want to exclude in a HashSet and check if they are already in there by using something like Hashset.Contains(Path.GetFileName(newPath)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
      HashSet<string> namesToExclude = new HashSet<string>()
      {
        "bla.dll",
        "blubb.exe"
      };
      string TargetDirectory = @"Copied";
      if (Directory.Exists(TargetDirectory))
      {
        Directory.Delete(TargetDirectory, true);
      }

      Directory.CreateDirectory(TargetDirectory);
      await Task.Delay(1000);

      string SourceDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

      Logger.LogInfo("Creating Backup of the Source Directory...");            
      if (Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory).Length == 0)
      {
        Logger.LogError("No Files found in this directory. " + SourceDirectory);
        return;
      }
      else
      {   
        //Now Create all of the directories         
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourceDirectory, TargetDirectory));

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
          if (!namesToExclude.Contains(Path.GetFileName(newPath)))
          {
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourceDirectory, TargetDirectory), true);
          }

        }
      }
```

Oh and as a sidenote, your code will not copy if there are only directories and no files inside the root directory, you might want to check for directories as well. And subdirectories will be a problem as well. You could use recursion to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir, this worked.
and yes, i need to do lots of small fixes in the code also need to add few other stuff as well. i was kinda rushed to solve this problem which i was facing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try, that should work:

```
    async Task<void> Copy(List<string> ExcludedNamesWithoutExtensions)
    {
        string TargetDirectory = @"Copied";
        if (Directory.Exists(TargetDirectory))
        {
            Directory.Delete(TargetDirectory, true);
        }

        Directory.CreateDirectory(TargetDirectory);

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        string SourceDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        Logger.LogInfo("Creating Backup of the Source Directory...");
        if (Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory).Length == 0)
        {
            Logger.LogError("No Files found in this directory. " + SourceDirectory);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Now Create all of the directories         
            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourceDirectory, TargetDirectory));
            //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
            foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                bool CanCopy = true;
                    string[] array = newPath.Split('\\')[newPath.Split('\\').Length - 1].Split('.');
                    string name = array[array.Length - 1];
                foreach (string s in ExcludedNamesWithoutExtensions)
                {
                    if (name != s)
                    {
                         CanCopy = false;
                         break;
                    }
                }
                if (CanCopy)
                        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourceDirectory, TargetDirectory), true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend using [Path.GetfileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) Instead of splitting.

Comment: Oh and you are also copying the files multiple times, one time for each of your ExcludedNamesWithoutExtensions.

Comment: Sorry, but as your File.Copy is still inside the foreach-loop - it still does.

Comment: I must sound really picky here, but the Op did not ask to ignore the file extension. And if you have a file named "my.cool.file.exe" you will get into trouble.

Comment: Op said based on their name, not the extensions.

Comment: I did understand the Op differently, but let him pick what he needs and not get into an argument here ;)